# Find contains class name in multiple classes

Tags: jquery, string, class, find, contain

I want to get the id in class like...

```
<div class="main demo id_111 test"></div>

<div class="main demo test id_222 test demo"></div>

<div class="id_3 main demo test  test demo"></div>
```

Result must be `111` , `222` and `3`

So I code like this

```
var id = $(".main").attr("class");
var id = id.split("id_");
var id = id[1].split(" ");
var id = id[0];

$("body").append(id);
```

But someone know better coding than mine ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/UHyaD/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regex :

```
var id = $(".main").attr("class").match(/id_(\d*)/)[1];
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/UHyaD/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` function:

```
var id = $(".main").attr("class").match(/\d+/g).join('');
```