# Removing 2 (multiple) matching classes in one regex

Tags: jquery, regex, matching

I done now but i have to call 2 times `.removeClass()` functions

How can I merge this to find the result in one regex call?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="one-abc two-cba three-bac"></div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('div')
  .removeClass(function(i,c){var m=c.match(/one-[a-z]{0,5}/);return m?m[0]:m;})
  .removeClass(function(i,c){var m=c.match(/two-[a-z]{0,5}/);return m?m[0]:m;});
```

**Demo :** http://jsbin.com/umoded/1/edit

---

[Find contains class name in multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877393/find-contains-class-name-in-multiple-classes)

[Remove matching class with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580143/remove-matching-class-with-regex)

Comment: I'm guessing this question assumes knowledge of another question... If that's the case please give a link pointing there so it is easier for future readers to follow what you want to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine both expressions in one, use `g`, and join the matches:

```
  var m = c.match(/(one-[a-z]{0,5}|two-[a-z]{0,5})/g);
  return m ? m.join(' ') : m;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/mnYpB/

Answer (score 3):

from api.jquery.com:

> More than one class may be removed at a time, separated by a space, from the set of matched elements, like so:
>   $('p').removeClass('myClass yourClass')

-->

```
.removeClass(function(i,c){
    var m=c.match(/one-[a-z]{0,5}/);
    var n=c.match(/two-[a-z]{0,5}/);
    return m+" "+n;});
```